# Where can I find the time and space complexity of the built-in sequence types in Python

Tags: python, performance, complexity-theory, big-o, sequences

I've been unable to find a source for this information, short of looking through the Python source code myself to determine how the objects work. Does anyone know where I could find this online?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Checkout the [TimeComplexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page on the py dot org wiki. It covers set/dicts/lists/etc at least as far as time complexity goes.

Answer (score 15):

Raymond D. Hettinger does [an excellent talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYUsssClE94) ([slides](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/9c6fb20dcc1755270722089d.html)) about Python's built-in collections called 'Core Python Containers - Under the Hood'. The version I saw focussed mainly on `set` and `dict`, but `list` was covered too.

There are also some photos of the pertinent slides from EuroPython in [a blog](http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/07/europython-2008-day-3.html).

Here is a summary of my notes on `list`:

- Stores items as an array of pointers. Subscript costs O(1) time. Append costs amortized O(1) time. Insert costs O(n) time.
- Tries to avoid `memcpy` when growing by over-allocating. Many small lists will waste a lot of space, but large lists never waste more than about 12.5% to overallocation.
- Some operations pre-size. Examples given were `range(n)`, `map()`, `list()`, `[None] * n`, and slicing.
- When shrinking, the array is `realloc`ed only when it is wasting 50% of space. `pop` is cheap.

Answer (score 2):

If your asking what I think your asking, you can find them [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=vpTAq4dnmuAC&pg=RA1-PA476&lpg=RA1-PA476&dq=Big-O+of+Python+data+structures&source=web&ots=AOM5B5D7yA&sig=deLGb6VrftTpnNYN6fILVbiirXM&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=7&ct=result#PRA1-PA479,M1)... page 476 and on.

It's written around optimization techniques for Python; It's mostly Big-O notation of time efficiencies not much memory.