# find if item's variable exists in list using python

Tags: python

How can I use python to check if a object in my list already contains the same name?

- Class Object **Team**

  - attribute: **name**

I have a list which contains multiple 'Teams'

**pseudo code**

```
teams = [Team name="Dolphins", Team name="Browns", Team name="Ravens"]
```

How can i test if the team 'Browns' already exists?
Is it just a simple for-loop going item by item, or does python have some shortcode to do this?

Comment: `if 'Dolphins' in teams'` EDIT: sorry i thought they were just simple strings. is it a class with the attribute name?

Comment: "I have a list..." That does not look like a Python list to me. It gives me `SyntaxError` when I run it. Do you mean you have a text file which your script is reading?

Comment: correct. its a class with attribute 'name'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi

Comment: I'm confused. Which is it? A text file or a class? Classes usually start with `class ClassName:`, which you don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list looks not pythony, but if we assume it is, then here is the way:

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

teams = [Team("Dolphins"), Team("Browns"), Team("Ravens")]

def checkIfNameExists(team_obj_list, the_name):
    for team in team_obj_list:
        if (team.name == the_name):
            return "Name " + the_name + " already exists"

print checkIfNameExists(teams, "Browns")
```

Answer (score 2):

If the team name is what defines equality, you can do something like this:

```
class Team(object):
    def __eq__(self, other_team):
        return self.name == other_team.name
```

And *then* you can simply do `if team in teams` (where team is an instance of `Team` and `teams` is a list of instances of `Team`).