# Find which variable equals a value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of variables in Python:

```
a = 1  
b = 0  
c = 0
```

These come from part of a script that gets user input for certain fields to process, so 1 means "do something to 'a'" and 0 means "do not include." So it would be useful to know which fields need to be used later in the script, i.e. which of them equal 1.

What's the best way to find which of a, b or c is equal to 1?

I tried this method (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi)):

```
test_list = [a,b,c]  
next((x for x in test_list if x == 1), None)
```

Which returns `1`, but I'm looking for it to return `a`. This is precondition, the next step in the script takes the variables that equal `1` and does something with them, by variable name rather than value.

I could do it long-hand like this:

```
if a == 1:
    print "a"
if b == 1:
...
```

but I suspect there's a nice Pythonic way to find the name of a variable from a list of variables that equals a specific value.

Comment: Why not, instead of having a ton of variables with different values, just put those values in a list?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense; variables don't have names. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Don't do things this way. Use a container, like a list, or a dictionary.

Comment: Seems like an X-Y problem. What are you trying to accomplish that leads you to want to do such an odd thing?

Comment: @FredLarson I would bet a homework assignment...

Comment: I appreciate the pointers. It's frustrating when asking a question for someone to say "don't do that," or "that's weird." I thought by asking a question it was clear that I didn't understand something. Also, not homework -- how is that relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a dictionary (a mapping) instead of a list, as names only reference objects but are not the objects themselves:

```
d = dict(a = 1, b = 2, c = 0)
print(next((k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1), None))
# a
```