# how to iterate list of objects

Tags: python, loops, object

I have a list of objects. I would like to check some string if that string exists as a field value any object in the list. for example,

```
class Ani:
    name = ''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name


animal1 = Ani('alica')
animal2 = Ani('rex')
animal3 = Ani('bobik')
animal4 = Ani('dobik')
animal5 = Ani('sobik')

a = [animal1, animal2, animal3,animal4,animal5]
```

my problem to write a code in order to see if there is an object with given name. for example "chip".

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. **There is no attempt to solve your task.** Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Duplicate: [find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi)

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the array of objects, and check with each object's `getName` function.

```
class Ani:
    name = ''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name


animal1 = Ani('alica')
animal2 = Ani('rex')
animal3 = Ani('bobik')
animal4 = Ani('dobik')
animal5 = Ani('sobik')

animals = [animal1, animal2, animal3,animal4,animal5]

searched_animal = 'rex'

for animal in animals:
  if animal.getName() == searched_animal:
    print('Found')
    break
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `any` plus a comprehension:

```
any(animal.getName() == "chip" for animal in animals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getName` method present in `Ani` class for this program

```
class Ani:
    name = ''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name


animal1 = Ani('alica')
animal2 = Ani('rex')
animal3 = Ani('bobik')
animal4 = Ani('dobik')
animal5 = Ani('sobik')

animals = [animal1, animal2, animal3,animal4,animal5]

key = 'chip'

flag=0
for animal in animals:
    if animal.getName() == key:
        print('Found')
        flag=1
        break

if flag==0:
    print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating a list containing anything is quite simple really. Like so:

```
animal_to_find = "someAnimal"
for animal in animals:
  if animal.getName() == animal_to_find:
    print("Found a match for: " + animal)
```