# Select agents by a condition out of the model and change that attribute in mesa?

Tags: python, mesa-abm

For an agent based modelling I'm doing with mesa & mesa-geo I need a way, to select and manipulate the agents out of the `model.py`.

For example, if you take the [Introductory Tutorial](https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/intro_tutorial.html#), each step you want a particular randomly picked percentage of all agents which have no money (self.wealth = 0) to receive one money.

Therefore you need to know from all agents the wealth, pick the ones with wealth zero, pick randomly an amount of them and set wealth = 1. But is there a way, to do this out of the `model.py`?

For my understanding, you can only get a list of the agents by `model.grid.agents`, but here you can't see there attributes and you can't change the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a solution. The keyword is object oriented programing.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi) is a question which answers this one quite good.
At the end I realised my problem with adding functions for finding the object by a attribute criteria and then changing the attributes of those.
As I already mentioned, the list of attributes can be accessed in the model itself by `self.space.agents` or `self.grid.agents`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).