# Python. Get value from json object if we know name

Tags: python, json

I have JSON and can get value using

```py
print(step_id['Steps'][0]['Id'])
```

But the position of `Id` key might be changed. However, its name `'Id'` won't change.

How to get value by using a key name? Prompt me, please.

Example of JSON file

```json
{
    "Steps": [
        {
            "Id": "UPSKGVQL6Y",
            "Config": {
                "Properties": {},
                "Args": []
            },
            "Status": {}
        }
    ],
    "ResponseMetadata": {}
}
```

Comment: What are the other locations where `Id` might be? In other dicts in the `Steps` list?

Comment: Loop through the array, and check if the dictionary has an `Id` key.

Comment: Can you show an example where it's not in the `0` index?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object in list that has attribute equal to some value (that meets any condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi)