# Image Classification for crosswords

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification

I am attempting to create an app that can read a British-style crossword.

The first step is to be able to recognise a crossword image and parse it into an appropriately sized array.

I have been attempting to use Microsoft Azure Custom Object Detection software whereby I upload images of crosswords, highlight the main grid, clues across and clues down and then train the model.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be working as the results I am getting after 100+ images indicates that identifying clues in such a way on a crossword grid is very difficult. Although the model states that the recall is at 48%, in reality it is closer to 5% when you insist upon a probability threshold of 50%. I am aware that 100+ images really isn't that many, but the results make me think I would need an image base in the thousands to achieve what I want. This would take a prohibitive amount of time and effort to implement.

So, is there a model out there that exists that can be modified to detect and parse crosswords? I have searched for one and haven't found anything suitable.

I have found resources such as [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) but it isn't obvious how, or indeed if, they can be modified to do what I want.

The model itself would need to be usable in TensorflowJS (my understanding is that there is a way to convert python models to TFJS).

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that may help you:

Hough line detection Algorithm

[Algorithms to classify and extract crossword grids from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447701/algorithms-to-classify-and-extract-crossword-grids-from-an-image)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Detecting_lines