# Managing big point lists, best approach?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, data-structures, dataset

I have hit a performance wall in my code and have decided to rewrite it, and need some advice on how to tackle this issue.
I have a huge list of optical flow data that consists of lists with a frame, X and Y coordinates.
like so:

```
[[[frame,x,y],[frame,x,y]],[[frame,x,y],[frame,x,y]]...]
```

I have uploaded a sample here: http://pastebin.com/ANUr8bwc

I need to find a way to manage this data so that I can do quick lookups and see what lists contain certain frames.

So far I have looped through all of the data to see what lists contain say frame 34 and 35 and then index them into a new list for reference.

```
thisFrame = 34
nextFrame = thisFrame + 1
if any(e[0] == thisFrame for e in item) and any(e[0] == nextFrame for e in item): #Check if the item contains this frame and next
    DoStuff()
```

Doing this a few thousand times for a list of 10.000+ points quickly turns into a bottleneck. So my idea was to make a dict for each frame and in that way easily be able to find what items are available on a certain frame:

```
{frame, [list1,list2,list3]}
```

But I think I better ask this time.
Is there a good goto method for storing and being able to do lookups in big datasets, to avoid looping through all of them every time you need to do so?

Comment: `I have hit a performance wall` how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Do you have duplicate frames? If not, you would be better off not storing the `frame` at all, and derive the index based on the frame you want to request.

Comment: So, can i merge these two frames: [[110, '79.607002', '76.638'], [111, '61.595001', '85.915001']]
AND 

[[110, '257.90201', '108.176'], [111, '232.58501', '108.98']]

Comment: @yopy I think so, that would in fact avoid the `any()` lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are one of Python's most heavily optimized data structures. Converting your data into a dictionary would take some time, but afterwards, lookups (e.g. `thisFrame in item`) are done in [`O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513906/2980246) time, which are much faster than lists.

Your best bet would be to convert into a dictionary, using some code like this:

N.B. It looks like your lists are nested twice, you'll have to slightly modify the iteration if this isn't the case.

```
item_dict = {}
for big_lst in item:
    for lst in big_lst:
        try:
            item_dict[lst[0]] += [lst[1:],] # Append to existing value
        except KeyError:
            item_dict[lst[0]] = [lst[1:],] # Initialize value
```

*Edit 02/05: try/except is faster*

`item_dict` will look like this, with duplicate frames merged so that a single frame lookup will return a list of [x, y] pairs.

```
item_dict = {
    1: [list1, list2, list3]
    2: [list1, list2]
    3: [list1]
    4: [list1, list2, list3]
}
```

Lookups from then on will be very fast:

```
thisFrame = 34
nextFrame = thisFrame + 1
if thisFrame in item_dict and nextFrame in item_dict:
    foo = item_dict[thisFrame] # e.g. [list1, list2]
    bar = item_dict[nextFrame] # e.g. [list1, list2, list3]
    DoStuff()
```

If you need to keep track of what parent list the individual [x, y] pairs belong to, you could add one additional element of each list which stores the index of the parent list in `item`:

```
item_dict = {}
for list_index, big_lst in enumerate(item):
    for lst in big_lst:
        if lst[0] in item_dict:
            item_dict[lst[0]] += [lst[1:]+[list_index],] # Append
        else:
            item_dict[lst[0]] = [lst[1:]+[list_index],] # Initialize
```

Then, a lookup like

```
parent_list = item_dict[thisFrame][2] # [x, y, list_index]
```

will return the parent list which can be accessed:

```
item[parent_list]
```

Comment: his lookup is not the key, he is trying to find out the key from the matching value, thats what i understood, so its not O(1)

Comment: @yopy the two `any` functions return a boolean value that checks whether `thisFrame` and `nextFrame` exist in the first index of any list in `item`. I believe the dictionary lookup towards the end of my answer does the same thing?

Comment: That was exactly what i was thinking. Having the index in the dict to refrence back to the main struc. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

What I am trying to do here :

First i tried to merge all the x,y to the unique frame by creating a dictionary called frame.
Second, i revert the dictionary by converting the value into key and key into value.

Please let me know if that works : else i ll modify or remove it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ast

dict_frame = dict()
def generate_datastructure():
    l = ''
    with open('2d_optical_tracking_data.txt', 'r') as fh:
        l = ast.literal_eval(fh.read())
    frame = dict()
    for ls in l:
        for elm in ls:
            key = elm[0]
            val_list = elm[1:]
            frame.setdefault(key, [])
            frame[key].extend(val_list)

    # convert all the value into set:
    for key, val in frame.iteritems():
        dict_frame[tuple(set(val))] = key

def lookup(key):
    print dict_frame

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tofind = '45.835999'
    generate_datastructure()
    for key, val in dict_frame.iteritems():
        if tofind in key:
            print val
```