# Python List Append Slow?

Tags: python, list, garbage-collection

i have to merge two text files together into one, and create a new list from that. The first one contains urls and the other one urlpaths/folder, which have to be applied to EVERY url. Im Working with lists, and its really slow, because its roughtly about 200,000 items.

Sample:

urls.txt:

```
 http://wwww.google.com
 ....
```

paths.txt:

```
 /abc
 /bce
 ....
```

Later, after the loop is finished, there should be a new list with

```
http://wwww.google.com/abc
http://wwww.google.com/bce
```

Python Code:

```
URLS_TO_CHECK = [] #defined as global, needed later

def generate_list():
  urls = open("urls.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
  paths = open("paths.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
  done = open("done.txt", "r").read().splitlines() #old done urls

  for i in range(len(urls)):
    for x in range(len(paths)):
        url = re.search('(http://(.+?)....)', urls[i]) #needed
        url = "%s%s" %(url.group(1), paths[x])
        if url not in URLS_TO_CHECK:
            if url not in done:
                URLS_TO_CHECK.append(url) ##<<< slow!
```

Already read some other threads about `map` function, disable `gc`, but cant use `map` function with my program. and disable `gc` didn't really help.

Comment: Try changing URLS_TO_CHECK to a set() instead, as long as ordering doesn't matter to you.

Comment: You could make `done` a set too, which would speed up the membership test. Have you done any profiling?

Comment: Have you even `profile`d your code? You are creating a lot of lists (`range(len(url))` etc.) , read all files to the memory instead of iterating over them, and honestly I think `append` is not a bottleneck here.

Comment: ^ yeah, what's the evidence that `append` is what's slow?

Comment: If `urls` is 200,000 elements long and so is  `paths`, it's not very surprising that your program is slow. That's 40 trillion iterations.

Comment: `URLS_TO_CHECK` and `done` could be dictionaries , so search time is reduced from O(N) to O(1)

Comment: or a set for that matter  :P

Comment: You should also try to `generate` urls instead of building whole list. I'll draft  some improvements and post a whole answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach takes advantage of things such as:

- quick look-up in set - O(1) instead of O(n)
- generating values on demand instead of building whole list as once
- reading from file in chunks instead of loading up whole data at once
- avoiding unnecessary regular expression

---

```
def yield_urls():
    with open("paths.txt") as f:
        paths = f.readlines() # needed in each iteration and iterates over, may be list

    with open("done.txt") as f:
        done_urls = set(f.readlines()) # needed in each iteration and looked up, set is O(1) vs O(n) in list 

    # resources are cleaned up after with

    with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
        for url in f: # iterate over list, not big list of ints generated before iteratiob, much quicker
            for subpath in paths:
                full_url = ''.join((url[7:], subpath)) # no regex means faster, maybe string formatting is quicker than join, you need to check
                # also, take care about trailing newlines in strings read from file
                if full_url not in done_urls:  # fast lookup in set
                    yield full_url  # yield instead of appending

# usage
for url in yield_urls():
    pass  # to something with url
```

Comment: Don't call `readlines` unless you need its argument - just use `list(f)` and `set(f)` instead. You're also using `''.join` where you should just use `+`: `url[7:] + subpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Search in Dictionaries is faster compared lists [Python: List vs Dict for look up table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table)

```
URLS_TO_CHECK = {} #defined as global, needed later

def generate_list():
  urls = open("urls.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
  paths = open("paths.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
  done = dict([(l, True) for l in open("done.txt", "r").read().splitlines()]) #old done urls

  for i in range(len(urls)):
    for x in range(len(paths)):
      url = re.search('(http://(.+?)....)', urls[i]) #needed
      url = "%s%s" %(url.group(1), paths[x])
      if not url in URLS_TO_CHECK:
        if not url in done:
          URLS_TO_CHECK[url] = True #Result in URLS_TO_CHECK.keys()
```

Comment: `urls = open("urls.txt", "r").read().splitlines()` and `paths = open("paths.txt", "r").read().splitlines()` using excessive use memory better use iterator

Comment: if use memory size is not a problem Might as well leave

Answer (score -1):

```
 URLS_TO_CHECK = set(re.findall("'http://(.+?)....'",open("urls.txt", "r").read()))
 for url in URLS_TO_CHECK:
     for path in paths:
         check_url(url+path)
```

will probably be much faster ... and I think its essentially the same ....

Comment: is this not the same?

Comment: Cant do that, because i have to add the paths (from paths.txt) to every url in urls.txt.