# Why is key search faster than iteration through python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't fundamentally understand why searching for a key in dictionary is faster than iterating through the keys of a dictionary to find a matching key. I imagine that when searching for a key in python with something like `key in dict` the background code will be iterating through keys to look for matches. So why would it be slower to do this manually with something like `for i in dict: key == i`?

Comment: "I imagine that when searching for a key in python with something like `key in dict` the background code will be iterating through keys to look for matches" - [you imagine wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: [Sorting and Searching](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201896850). With the appropriate choice of algorithms and data structures, you can find stuff in log(n) or less.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table) and many other questions about how dictionary/set lookups are implemented in terms of performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because dictionaries in python are implemented using hash tables. Think something similar to indices in a relational database, which make key seeking operations faster.

[Reference](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/)

Answer (score 3):

You imagine incorrectly: searching for a single key uses a hashing function, so it's an indirect reference (two-step computation) to the needed location in memory.  Think of it as an array reference of the form

```
array[hash_function(key)]
```