# Python: saving previously visited coordinates of a binary array for AStar

Tags: python, a-star

I am creating an A* algorithm in python, and I am trying to figure out how to save the locations that my algorithm has previously visited within a binary array such as the one below.

```
nmap = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0]
    ])
```

The only way I can think of is to save the location of the previously visited binary numbers via coordinates. For instance,

```
nmap[0][0]
```

would save the first binary number in a list or dictionary, and thus would not be revisited. The problem is I am not sure how to achieve this. Please keep in mind that I want to save the coordinates as the algorithm is running instead of previously writing out the coordinates. My reasoning for this is if I have an array with thousands of integers, previously writing this code could be quite cumbersome. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Think about it. How did you know there is a wall, or an obstacle, on the map? You can think the nodes in the close list is equivalent to a wall.

Comment: @EvenYoung I was going to incorporate obstacles in my algorithm by not allowing movement where there is a 1. My main issue if figuring out how to hold state on previously visited nodes without having a specific key assigned to each node.

Comment: My previous question is a hint. Just set the node to 1 on the map when you visit it the first time, then treat it as an obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious choice is a `Set`. It gives [amortized O(1) lookup performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513906/3795219). You can add visited nodes to the `visitedSet` by using the `add` method, and you can check if a node is in your `visitedSet` using the `in` operator:

```
>>> from sets import Set
>>> visitedSet = Set()
>>> visitedSet.add( (1,2) )
>>> print( (0,0) in visitedSet )
False
>>> print( (1,2) in visitedSet)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily save the indexes to the coordinates in a list of tuples for that:

```
visited = [(0,0), (2,0)...]
```

Comment: I want them to save the coordinates as the algorithm is running instead of previously writing out the coordinates. My reasoning for this is if I have an array with thousands of integers, previously writing this code out could be quite cumbersome.

Comment: @bnicholl, i cant understand what you try to achieve then, could you expand your example?