# Create dictionary from list elements in Python

Tags: python

I have a list similar to the following:

```
my_list =
    [(1, 'item_19'),
     (2, 'item_20'),
     (3, 'item_21'),
     (4, 'item_22'),
     (5, 'item_23'),
     (6, 'item_24'),
     (7, 'item_25'),
     (8, 'item_26'),
     (9, 'item_27'),
     (10, 'item_28'),
     (11, 'item_29'),
     (12, 'item_30'),
     (13, 'item_31'),
     (14, 'item_32'),
     (15, 'item_33'),
     (16, 'item_34'),
     (17, 'item_35')]
```

I would like to make a dictionary of each element of the list, i.e. `1:'item_19',2:'item_20'`

I currently do this:

```
list_1 = [l[0] for l in my_list]
list_2 = [l[1] for l in my_list]
```

and then zip the two lists

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list_1,list_2))
```

However there are more than a million element in `my_list`, so is this the best way to do this, or is there a quicker/more optimal way to do it(Memory wise).

To put this in context, I want a lookup table to check if elements in `my_dict` already exist in a different dictionary `my_dict_old`

Comment: Just `dict(my_list)`?

Comment: Also, if all keys are numbers and are not huge you can put all of them into array. Index would be the key

Comment: with your code you are basiclly rebuilding your list, `my_list ==  zip(list_1,list_2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin `dict` function takes a list of tuples, which is exactly what you are providing:

```
>>> list_foo = [(1, 'item_1'), (2, 'item_2')]
>>> dict(list_foo)
{1: 'item_1', 2: 'item_2'}
```

If all you need to do is check for an item's existence, consider using `set`, as `i in my_set` is much faster than `i in my_dict.values()`, [see the Python documentation on performance](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for more info. On my machine, for example, a lookup in a haystack of 10k entries is `.443s` with `dict.values()`, vs `<.000s` for `set`. If you need to associate values with the entries, then use a dictionary, otherwise use a set. For a more in-depth examination of lists vs. dictionaries (and also sets for the most part), refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513906/3882704).

Answer (score 0):

`dict` accepts list of tuples, so you can just use your original list:

```
my_dict = dict(my_list)
```

And you are actually doing the same thing while calling `zip`

Also, if all keys are numbers and are not huge you can put all of them into array. Index would be the key. Though this solution depends on the actual task and might not be useful in some cases