# Python Pandas Vectorize removing unpopular hashtags out of Strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, series

I have a function that looks through tweets and extracts only popular hashtags and handles. The problem is that I have a large data set and this takes 10 or more minute to finish. I'm looking for a way to "vectorize" this function to make it run faster.

I already have a list of popular hashtags

```
def get_popular_hashes(myString):
   myList = myString.split(' ')
   newStr = ''
   for x in myList:
      if x in popular_tags_list:
         newStr+=' '+x
   return newStr  

tweets2["popularHandles"] = tweets2.HashesAndHandles.apply(get_popular_hashes)
```

If I can discover a way to do this without the `.apply()`, that's even better.

For example:

```
["I'm hungry. let's eat! #curlyfries @jackinthebox",
 "I got a 4.0 last semester! #scholarship #hardwork #stackoverflow"]
```

might turn into:

```
["@jackinthebox",
"#stackoverflow"
]
```

Thanks so much you guys!

Comment: If `popular_tags_list` is a list of significant length, [replacing it with a `set` would work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513882/1270789).

Comment: Also, you could optimize construction of `newStr` a bit: `newStr = ' '.join(filter(popular_tags_set.__contains__, myList))` or `newStr = ' '.join(x for x in myList if x in popular_tags_set)`

Comment: get_popular_hashtags has a length of 14 thousand.

Comment: That actually worked really well you two!

Comment: What is the purpose of '.__contains__' here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution based on the your comments. Its working great and MUCH MUCH faster! So exciting! 10-15 mins down to like 3 seconds - (not even joking).

```
def trim_unpopular_hashes_vectorized(myStr):
   myList = myStr.split(' ')
   newStr = ' '.join(filter(popular_tags_set.__contains__, myList))
   return newStr     



popular_tags_set=set(popular_tags_list)

tweets2["popularHandles"] = tweets2.HashesAndHandles.apply(trim_unpopular_hashes_vectorized)
```