# Is there a better way to create string aliases in Python than using a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a program that takes some string as a input. However, that same string can be written in many equivalent ways.
Tinkering with Python dictionaries, I found out that making some dictionary like

```
things = {
"a1" : "a",
"a2" : "a",
}
```

works out for what I want to do (which is iterating through an excel column and getting the adjacent value for "a" by inputting either "a1" or "a2"), but I was wondering is there's a better way to do this, since this will be super expensive whenever I'll decide to add more entries to the dictionary.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table)

Comment: Why do you think it would be expensive (I assume you mean CPU time with that?)?

Comment: To be fair I'm not 100% sure about that since I'm just starting out with Python, but I'd assume that iterating through a dictionary and comparing strings is not really fast. But I also think I can easily be wrong since I'm not even sure how that happens in that case in particular.