# Is it posible to save an stream in a variable?

Tags: python, image, opencv, stream, camera

I am trying to save 10 seconds of buffered video using Python, in particular '.h264' format.

In order to do so, I have been using a PiCamera connected to a Raspberry Pi and the script shown below. The main road block I am facing right now is that instead of saving the file directly to a location [stream.copy_to(str(time)+'.h264')]  I would like to save it to a variable in order to perform certain operations (e.g. change video resolution) before finally saving it. Any idea how this can be achieve?

Thanks in advance!

```
import time
import io
import os 
import picamera
import datetime as dt
from PIL import Image
import cv2 

#obtain current time
def return_currentTime():
    return dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#trigger event declaration
def motion_detected():
    while True:
        print ("Trigger event(y)?")
        trigger = input ()
        if trigger =="y":
            time = return_currentTime()
            print ("Buffering...")
            stream.copy_to(str(time)+'.h264')           
           
        else: 
           camera.stop_recording()
           break
        
#countdown timer 
def countdown (t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod (t,60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t-=1
    print('Buffer available!')
   

camera = picamera.PiCamera()

camera.resolution = (640, 480)

stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds = 5)

#code will work using h264 as format
camera.start_recording (stream, format = 'h264')
countdown(5)
motion_detected()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Raspberry Pi, but I have an idea of how you can do it.

- 1. I used `VideoStream` which also supports `PiCamera` so you can use the below code.

  - ```py
    stream = VideoStream(usePiCamera=False,
                     resolution=(640, 480),
                     framerate=32).start()

    # Wait for a two-second for warming the webcam.
    time.sleep(2.0)
    ```
- 2. Start getting frames

  - ```py
    while True:
        frame = stream.read()
        countdown(5)
        motion_detected()
    ```
- 3. Modify `motion_detected()` for saving frames.

     ```py
     while True:
         frame = stream.read()
         countdown(5)
         motion_detected(frame)
     ```
- 4. Now we need to store frames either using `array` or `dictionary`.

  - Dictionary is faster than the array. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table))
  - We need to initialize a global dictionary on top of the project file.

    ```py
    import time
    import datetime as dt
    from imutils.video import VideoStream

    dictionary = {}
    count = 0
    ```
  - We need to modify the `motion_detected` method, we start by initializing the input parameter

    ```py
    # trigger event declaration
    def motion_detected(input_frame):
    ```
  - Second, we define the global variables inside `motion_detected`

    ```py
    # trigger event declaration
    def motion_detected(input_frame):
        global dictionary
        global count
    ```
  - Unfortunately, VideoStream object has no `copy_to` attribute, therefore I have to directly assign frame to the dictionary:

    ```py
    def motion_detected(input_frame):
        global dictionary
        global count
        while True:
            print("Trigger event(y)?")
            trigger = input()
            if trigger == "y":
                current_time = return_current_time()
                print("Buffering...")
                # stream.copy_to(str(current_time) + '.h264')
                dictionary[count] = input_frame
                count += 1
                if count == 10:
                    print("\n10 frames are stored\n")
             else:
                 stream.stop()
         break
    ```
- 5. Now we can perform certain operations like detecting edges.

  - ```py
    while True:
        frame = stream.read()
        countdown(5)
        motion_detected(frame)

        for stored_frame in dictionary.values():
            result = cv2.Canny(image=stored_frame,
                               threshold1=50,
                               threshold2=100)
    ```
- 6. Output:

  - [image]
- 7. Saving the frames

  - To save the frames, you need to enumerate over the stored frames.

    - ```py
      for count, stored_frame in enumerate(dictionary.values()):
      ```
  - Then, apply your operation:

    - ```py
      for count, stored_frame in enumerate(dictionary.values()):
          result = cv2.Canny(image=stored_frame,
                             threshold1=50,
                             threshold2=100)
      ```
  - Save it to a folder.

    - ```py
       for count, stored_frame in enumerate(dictionary.values()):
           result = cv2.Canny(image=stored_frame,
                              threshold1=50,
                              threshold2=100)

            cv2.imwrite("output/frame_{}.png".format(count), result)
      ```
  - If you want to loop through multiple times, the above code won't work. In this case, you need to iniitialize loop above the `while` loop.

    - ```py
      counter = 0

      while True:
          frame = stream.read()
          countdown(5)
          motion_detected(frame)

          for stored_frame in dictionary.values():
              result = cv2.Canny(image=stored_frame,
                                 threshold1=50,
                                 threshold2=100)

              cv2.imwrite("output/frame_{}.png".format(counter), result)
           counter += 1
      ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import time
import datetime as dt
from imutils.video import VideoStream

dictionary = {}
count = 0


# obtain current time
def return_current_time():
    return dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


# trigger event declaration
def motion_detected(input_frame):
    global dictionary
    global count
    while True:
        print("Trigger event(y)?")
        trigger = input()
        if trigger == "y":
            current_time = return_current_time()
            print("Buffering...")
            # stream.copy_to(str(current_time) + '.h264')
            dictionary[count] = input_frame
            count += 1
            if count == 10:
                print("\n10 frames are stored\n")
        else:
            stream.stop()
            break


# countdown timer
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('Buffer available!')


stream = VideoStream(usePiCamera=False,
                     resolution=(640, 480),
                     framerate=32).start()

time.sleep(2.0)

counter = 0

while True:
    frame = stream.read()
    countdown(5)
    motion_detected(frame)

    for stored_frame in dictionary.values():
        result = cv2.Canny(image=stored_frame,
                           threshold1=50,
                           threshold2=100)

        cv2.imwrite("output/frame_{}.png".format(counter), result)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: my apologies for the late response. I checked your code and unfortunately no output is being generated. Also, is the video buffer function maintained?  I don't think we are keeping it under your code.

Comment: Did you debug? maybe the frame is coming null. I've tested the code, if you look at the 6th step, I have an example output.

Comment: Yes, I did. I ran it using raspberry pi and pi camera. No outputs whatever...

Comment: What is the output of the frame? Is it null or image?

Comment: Nada...it outputs nothing :/