# TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument when moving Kivy application to 2.0.0

Tags: python, kivy, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

Is anyone able to advise?

I have an application running perfectly well on Pi3/ArchLinuxArm/Kivy1.11.

I am attempting to move the application to Pi4/RasPiOS Lite (Buster)/Kivy2.0.0.
Now a piece of code where I generate buttons dynamically is failing with:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Main.py", line 57, in <module>
     main()
   File "Main.py", line 34, in main
     Display.Display()
   File "/home/automate/Display.py", line 657, in Display
     DisplayApp().run()
   File "/home/automate/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/home/automate/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "/home/automate/Display.py", line 649, in build
     sm.add_widget(ControlLightsScreen(name='c_lights'))
   File "/home/automate/Display.py", line 315, in __init__
     on_press = self.on_event
   File "/home/automate/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 121, in __init__
     super(ButtonBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/automate/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/label.py", line 318, in __init__
     super(Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/automate/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The segment of code in question is:

```
    for j in range(len(Lights.lights)):
        i = j
        button = Button(
                        text = Lights.lights[i][2], font_size = 24,
                        text_size = (160,60),
                        halign = 'center', valign = 'center',
                        size_hint_x = None, width = 188,
                        size_hint_y = None, height = 68,
                        id=str(i),
                        color = black,
                        background_normal = '',
                        background_color = grey,
                        on_press = self.on_event
                       )
        self.mylights.append([grey,button])
        grid.add_widget(button)
```

I have tried removing the line where the error is reported ("on_press = self.on_event") and all this does is to move the reported error to the line above.
With that entire section of code commented out, the application runs okay.

Similar code, generating labels dynamically is still fully functional.

Have I done something wrong or has there been some change between 1.11.1 and 2.0.0 that I need to allow for?

The startup diagnostics are:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/automate/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-02-04_10.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/automate/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'VMware, Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
```

Comment: Try removing the `id=str(i),` and see if  that helps.

Comment: Ha, yes!  I'd just been playing and came to the conclusion that this is the line causing the problem.  So, why is that line a problem?  What should it be? Why did it work under 1.11?

Comment: I need something, available in the event handler, allowing me to index into the mylights list.

Comment: Whenever you create a new widget instance, its `__init__()` method is called. Typically, that `__init__()` method removes property settings that it recognizes from the `kwargs` provided to it. Then it passes the remaining `kwargs` to its super `__init__()` which does the same. Unclaimed `kwargs` end up getting passed to `object.__init__()` which does not accept any `kwargs`, causing the error. I suggest changing your `mylights` list to a dictionary with the `id` as the key.

Comment: @John Anderson - thanks for your response.  I'll try to assimilate the info you provide, but I have some immediate questions! ... 1) what I was doing seems to have been common practice, I've found responses to other questions on stackoverflow, suggesting exactly what I was doing: id=str(i), so what can you use as an id?  2) clearly, this was working perfectly well in 1.11 - why has the behaviour changed?   3) Even if I change to a dictionary, what do I pass as id?

Comment: Are there additional overheads of using a dictionary in place of a list?  I've not used any dictionaries, yet, in my move to Python coding (I started programming in 1970, using FORTRAN IV with hand-punched cards!).

Comment: Yes, the behavior has changed in newer versions of kivy and I do not know why. You can use almost anything for an `id`, however it won't be available in any `ids` dictionary unless you assign that `id` in `kv`. Note that the `ids` created by `kv` is just a dictionary.  For performance, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513882/python-list-vs-dict-for-look-up-table). By the way, I started on punched cards, too (but I used a card punch machine). :-)

Comment: I reported this as an issue on kivy/github.  The response surprises me - id is not a button property.  Yet, it used to work perfectly and it seems that others have been using it.  So, I need to find another method of passing an index from the button into the on_event code for that button.

Comment: So when you have Python code that uses self.ids.widget_name, where widget_name is assigned as an id in a markup file, it no longer works and I have to recode everything?

Comment: I don't know which widgets this applies to - it may just be relevant to buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I am reliably informed that 'id' is not a button property, despite the fact that it behaved as such prior to v2.0.0

The solution, of course, is simple.  Remove id from the list of assigned properties for the button but add a new line, immediately below the call of the button code, `button.id = i`.  Then obj.id can be referenced in the on_event code:

```
    for j in range(len(Lights.lights)):
        i = j
        button = Button(
                        text = Lights.lights[i][2], font_size = 24,
                        text_size = (160,60),
                        halign = 'center', valign = 'center',
                        size_hint_x = None, width = 188,
                        size_hint_y = None, height = 68,
                        color = black,
                        background_normal = '',
                        background_color = grey,
                        on_press = self.on_event
                       )
        button.id = i
        self.mylights.append([grey,button])
        grid.add_widget(button)


def on_event(self, obj):
    myid = obj.id
```